# Intermediary Action on Structured Streaming Dataframe (Head / Take / First)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to achieve a simple logic : 
I have a streaming Dataframe, Listening to incoming files on a directory, and I would like to do a specific transformation depending on the first record's field. 
Out of the box, **this operation is not supported** (hence the error) *BUT*, I am quasi certain there has to be  a way to achieve this somehow. Note that I do not need to process the whole file every time before branching.

*(I may be mistaken as structured streaming may be processing record by record and group in micro batches so I may need to test for my FOO/BAR field for every iteration. Not sure of that. Any clarification/solution is welcome.)*

FILE 1
FILE 2
FILE 3
...

PROCESS FILE 1 => IF FIRST RECORD IS OF TYPE FOO do FOO JOIN
______________ => IF FIRST RECORD IS OF TYPE BAR do BAR JOIN

PROCESS FILE 2
....

```
#Define Streaming Dataframe
DF = spark.readStream.schema(myschema).csv('/data/input')

#Test for an event type
EVENT_TYPE = DF.select('EVENT_TYPE').head().EVENT_TYPE #UNSUPPORTED

#If Foo Do Foo Transformation
if (EVENT_TYPE == 'FOO'):
    DF_NEXT = (DF.join(DF_FOO, DF.ID == DF_FOO.ID)

#If Bar Do Bar Transformation
elif (EVENT_TYPE == 'BAR'):
    DF_NEXT = (DF.join(DF_BAR, DF.ID == DF_BAR.ID) 

#Write Stream
DF_NEXT.writeStream.format("csv") \
                        .option("checkpointLocation",'/check') \
                        .outputMode("append") \
                        .start("/data/output")
```

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 
>   'Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()'